# I can`t update ubuntu

Tags: updates

this is what happens when I try to update, update manager (Requires installation of untrusted packages) how can I fix this  please

Comment: Enable Repositories by `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"` in Terminal and then `sudo apt-get update`